# Show menu item after condition - jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I show a menù item after a condition?
I use jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE template.

**page.blade.php**

```
    @if (is_string($item))
    <li class="header">{{ $item }}</li>
@else
    <li class="{{ $item['class'] }}">
        <a href="{{ $item['href'] }}"
           @if (isset($item['target'])) target="{{ $item['target'] }}" @endif
        >
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-{{ $item['icon'] or 'circle-o' }} {{ isset($item['icon_color']) ? 'text-' . $item['icon_color'] : '' }}"></i>
            <span>{{ $item['text'] }}</span>
            @if (isset($item['label']))
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                    <span class="label label-{{ $item['label_color'] or 'primary' }} pull-right">{{ $item['label'] }}</span>
                </span>
            @elseif (isset($item['submenu']))
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
            @endif
        </a>
        @if (isset($item['submenu']))
            <ul class="{{ $item['submenu_class'] }}">
                @each('adminlte::partials.menu-item', $item['submenu'], 'item')
            </ul>
        @endif
    </li>
@endif
```

I would use a condition for show an item...if()...

Answer (score 0):

Use `@foreach` instead.

```
@foreach($adminlte->menu() as $item)
    @if($item==some_condition)
       @include('adminlte::partials.menu-item-top-nav', $item)
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Have a look at [this](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-blade) link for better understanding.

Comment: I get an error: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: show your `partial.menu-item-top-nav` and where exactly did you get error??